# Html tag in string C#

Tags: c#, html, string, tags, dom

Need html tag img from string

I have  string

```
string s = "<img src=\"@Url.Content(\"~/Content/skin/Office2010Blue.png\")\" style=\"width: 100px;height: 100px;\" />";
var html = new HtmlDocument();



@html.CreateElement(s) does not work
```

I have no picture only HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode;

Comment: Not quite sure what's going on here, part of it looks like a Razor style markup... Is this a HTML doc? Is this an ASP.NET application running on IIS? Is this an ASP.NET MVC application? Just what is going on here?

Comment: this is mvc (razor) I try to create element from string

Comment: comes to me string with html tag and I need to create html doc and see picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use data directly inside img instead of lining to file

so you can

```
string s = "<img src=\""+getImageFromFile("~/Content/skin/Office2010Blue.png","image/png")+"\" style=\"width: 100px;height: 100px;\" />";
var html = new HtmlDocument();



@html.CreateElement(s)


public string getImageFromFile(String url, String imgType)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(url), 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read)){
        byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    }
    string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes);
    return "data:"+imgType+";base64,+"encodedData; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I can not check because it is something wrong with path Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\~\Content\skin\Office2010Blue.png'.

Comment: thank you this method works but it is same result that I have written I not see picture only HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode I need to parse this string to html document